# How to set default_order_line when opening sale order form?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to set default order line to sale order when it is being opened from opportunity (pipeline) using button "New Quotation".
What I have so far (it didn't work):

```
<record id="crm_case_form_view_oppor_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.oppor.inherited.crm2</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <button name="%(sale_crm.sale_action_quotations_new)d" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="context">{
                'search_default_partner_id': partner_id,
                'default_partner_id': partner_id,
                'default_team_id': team_id,
                'default_order_line': [(0, 0, {
                    'product_id': product_id,
                    'product_uom': 1,
                    'price_unit': 1,
                    'product_qty': 1,
                }
                )]
            }
            </attribute>
        </button>

    </field>
</record>
```

This solution looks simple and makes sense. However, o matter what field I pass to order line it doesn't work. I remember doing this with purchase order line and worked fine, however with sale order line it is something different. Error (not to much info given):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2908
Traceback:
 Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.rows']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error: Error: NameError: name 'invoice_status' is not defined
at Object.exception (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2908:7)
at Engine.eval (eval at _render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2950:73), <anonymous>:24:29)
at Engine._render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2949:296)
at Engine.render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2949:151)
at Engine._render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2953:57)
at Engine.render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:2949:151)
at Class.render (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/411-539d35f/web.assets_backend.js:2085:149)
at http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/411-539d35f/web.assets_backend.js:2102:46
at http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:547:681
at fire (http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/410-984e26b/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
```

If you have any exeprience regarding this problem share your opinions, maybe I shouldn't waste my time and offer something different to my client? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you remove this code what you did should not raise this kind of error. And see if the error still appear if so look for the mistake if not then try rewrite it part by part and see what exactly happened

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if that is the correct button you extend in the view. Shouldn't it be the button on the opening wizard, where to put the default values into context.

Another thing:

> Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.rows']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error: Error: NameError: name 'invoice_status' is not defined

There is something wrong with the view definition here

Comment: It is completely standard view made by odoo so I am pretty sure everything is fine here. I am just trying to add default_order_line to the context.